# Refactor local variable name using Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have this simple situation. I'd like to refactor the name of the role variable:

[image]

It looks like Visual Studio Code is smart enough to know that "roles" in the URL should not be touched.

I just want to refactor the name of the variable in a single file, in a single scope, not the whole file and definitely not multiple files!

If I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>, it will bring me to a menu which by default refactors the name in multiple files or a whole single file, but I just want to refactor the name in a single function scope!

Answer (score 251, accepted):

Use [rename symbol](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/editingevolved#_rename-symbol) instead of the standard find/replace. Rename is bound to <kbd>F2</kbd> by default.

Rename symbol will know to only touch the local `roles` references in your example. Visual Studio Code ships with rename support for JavaScript and TypeScript. Other languages may require installing a language extension.

Comment: man, is there a way to use something easier than the f2 key? that's really difficult to use. Why are there not more right-click options?

Comment: Right click on the symbol. It should be there. You can also [rebind](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) this to whatever keyboard shortcut you want

Comment: The context menu item does not show up if current language server does not support the feature.

Comment: macOs 1.29.0 Code - Insiders  is : cmd+f2  (Change All Occurrences)

Comment: In my case, is CTRL + F2. I'm currently using version 1.30.2

Comment: Note that "Change All Occurences" is different from "Rename Symbol". "Change All Occurences" seems to be limited to the current document, while "Rename Symbol" propagates through the project. In addition to that, "Change All Occurences" will also happily rename properties of different objects, if they are named the same (e.g. if you have two objects `a.SomeValue:string` and `b.SomeValue:number` and change the `SomeValue` property of a with ctrl+F2, it will also rename the property of b, even if they are different types. "Rename Symbol" will only rename the property of the type.

Comment: `Rename Symbol` uses language smarts to rename a symbol in all places it is referenced. `Change All Occurrences` is text operation that renames every occurrence of the selected text in a file; it's the same as pressing cmd+D a bunch to create multi-cursors for the selected text

Comment: There is something weird happening to VS Code. Sometimes `F2` works but most of the time I have to use `CTRL+F2`.

Comment: Function keys may work differently on some keyboard, but you can always [change the keybinding](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) for rename to whatever key or key combination you wish

Answer (score 49):

Use *Rename Symbol*. It is defined by default with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>.

However, keep in mind that the variable, definition, function, etc., that you're changing, will be changed in the file itself, not only the scope. Visual Studio Code for now doesn't have an implementation for renaming a variable in a scope (for example, a variable inside a function). So keep that in mind.

[Visual Studio Code - change all occurrences](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/7213)

Comment: No idea if it was changed after this answer was posted but there're currently two different commands: Rename Symbol (F2) and Change All Occurrences (Ctrl+F2). The smart one if the first one as far as I know.

Comment: Just to add, be careful when using this, I just used it and it changed every instance throughout a whole project not just the file I was working on and vscode could not reverse it, it just came up with an error saying refactor failed. Thank god for Git is all I can say.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Ctrl+F2 seems at least somewhat smart too. `$true` does not get selected when I right-click on _letter t_ in `$t` in a .ps1 file and Change All Occurrences.

Answer (score 40):

For macOS users: Use <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> to rename a variable inside a code block.

Comment: For me, just `Fn + F2`

Answer (score 8):

To open your user and **workspace settings**, use the following Visual Studio Code menu command:

On **Windows/Linux**: Menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Settings*. On **macOS**: *Code* → *Preferences* → *Settings*.

You can also open the Settings editor from the Command Palette (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>) with *Preferences*, open *Settings* or use the keyboard shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>).

[image]

In the search bar, enter `keybindings.json`, and add this below code:

```json
{
  "command": "editor.action.changeAll",
  "key": "ctrl+f2",
  "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
}
```

and

```json
{
  "command": "editor.action.rename",
  "key": "f2",
  "when": "editorHasRenameProvider && editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
}
```

In the keybindings.

<kbd>F2</kbd> appears to work across all files, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> in the current file only.

Comment: do you mean to say `keybindings.json` instead of `settings.json`?

Comment: the command `editor.action.changeAll` will do this based on **text** values where `editor.action.rename` will do this based on **reference**.
That's why, if you export/import a variable/function name, it'll rename across files. Be aware of this!

Also, if you want to rename **all** references, and not use aliases (like `originalName as newName`) you can change this in `settings.json`:   
```"javascript.preferences.useAliasesForRenames": false```

Comment: On linux `XFCE4` `ctrl+f2` change the workspace (virtual desktop) .

Answer (score 4):

1. select the name with ***F2***
2. type the new name
3. press ***ENTER***

   [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/refactoring#_rename-symbol)